# I don't understand this expression tree

Tags: c#, expression-trees

```
public static Expression<Func<int, int, int>> CreateExpressionTreeLambdaExpression()
{
    return (x, y) => x * y;
}
```

So I understand that if I wanted to test this method I could do like so, which evaluates to true.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestLambdaExpressions_ExpressionTreeLambdaExpression()
{
    var expression = MultiplyDelegate.CreateExpressionTreeLambdaExpression();
    var function = expression.Compile();
    Assert.AreEqual(6, function(2, 3));
}
```

What I don't seem to grasp is the three int's inside the Expression.  Where is the third int being used?  Is this some sort of reference to itself?

Comment: Have you read the documentation for [`Func<T1, T2, TResult>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534647(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: Thanks Jon, no I haven't. I was glossing over this part of MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx your suggested link clearly explains what I was missing as well as Jan's answer below.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The two parameters are `int`s and the result is an `int`. That makes three `int`s.